# Round decimal place only when number before decimal is 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I have a query

```sql
UPDATE T_rate SET discount= ROUND(@discount_calculated,2)
```

`@discount_calculated` is calculated based on some logic If `@discount_calculated = 0.04567812` then do round of to two place as `0.05`.

If `@discount_calculated = -0.0352312` then do round of to two place as `-0.04`.

If `@discount_calculated = 1.00000012` then no need of round off, keep it as is.

Basically if number before decimal is 0, then round off, else should not round of. `@discount_calculated` can be negative too . This needs to be updated for all records in the table Looking for a query.

Comment: why not just apply a where clause discount < 1 and discount >-1?

Comment: Note that a column's precision, scale, and length can't vary from row to row. This means that when rounded, `0.04567812` won't be stored `0.05` but `0.05000000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the value is between -1 and 1 and do round on it: `case when abs(@discount_calculated) < 1 then round(@discount_calculated,2) else @discount_calculated end`. [Example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=23abcac5650d3b503f8b7967d659c0cc).